# Get a local json file on NativeScript

Tags: json, nativescript

How to get a local big json data?

I have tried this, but I had no success:

```
var sa = require("./shared/resources/sa.json");
var array = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray(sa);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [file-system](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/file-system/HOW-TO) module to read the file and then parse it with `JSON.parse()`:

```
var fs = require('file-system');

var documents = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
var jsonFile = documents.getFile('shared/resources/sa.json');
var array;
var jsonData;

jsonFile.readText()
.then(function (content) {
    try {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(content);
        array = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Could not parse JSON file');
    }
}, function (error) {
    throw new Error('Could not read JSON file');
});
```

Here's a [real life example of how I'm doing it in a NativeScript app](https://github.com/emiloberg/oppna-program-reklistan-app/blob/master/src/app/shared/utils/DataLoader.js#L46-L64) to read a 75kb/250 000 characters big JSON file.

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript:

```
import {knownFolders} from "tns-core-modules/file-system";

export class Something {
    loadFile() {
        let appFolder = knownFolders.currentApp();
        let cfgFile = appFolder.getFile("config/config.json");
        console.log(cfgFile.readTextSync());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of TypeScript  version 2.9.x and above (in NativeScript 5.x.x is using versions 3.1.1 and above) we can now use `resovleJsonModule` option for `tsconfig.json`. With this option, the JSON files can now be imported just as modules and the code is simpler to use, read and maintain.

For example, we can do:

```
import config from "./config.json";

console.log(config.count); // 42
console.log(config.env); // "debug"
```

All we need to do is to use TypeScript 2.9.x and above and enable the propety in tsconfig.json

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

A sample project demonstrating the above can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-resolve-json)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add one more thing, which might be even easier. You can simply write the content of your JSON file in a data.js file, or whatever name you would like to use, and export it as an array. Then you can just require the data.js module.