# Fetch a local JSON (in project)

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript and I'd like to fetch a JSON that is a part of my projet.
How do I do so?

The following failed:

`app/data/util.js`

```js
import json from "../data/urls"; // Attempting to fetch urls.json
```

As a result:

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
Error: Cannot find module '../data/urls'
File: (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:435:120)

StackTrace: 
    webpackMissingModule(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:435:45)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:435:131)
    at ./data/utils.js(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:504:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:9:69)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:397:187)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./components/Home.vue(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:345:92)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:246:74)
    at ./app.js(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:306:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
    at require(:1:266)


Error: Cannot find module '../data/urls'
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:662)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:654)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

No matter if I attempt to fetch `~/data/urls` or `../data/urls`, the error is the same (with the minor path difference)

Later on, I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414119/get-a-local-json-file-on-nativescript), but I'm pretty sure that there's a simpler to way to fetch a JSON of the current project, right?

Answer (score 1):

you should determine the file extension too,
so it should be like:

```
import json from "../data/urls.json";
```